# Open file explorer in ionic via $ionicActionSheet.show()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to open file explorer in my ionic app when user clicks on button in `Ionic ActionSheet`. This can be simply accomplished by putting `<input type="file">` in HTML templates. But I am giving two options in actionsheet

1. open camera
2. open file explorer
   I use `$cordovaCamera` plugin to open camera but I have no idea how to open file explore.Here is my code for reference

```js
$ionicActionSheet.show({
    buttons: [{ text: 'Open File Explorer //or <input type="file">' },
    { text: 'Open Camera' }],
     buttonClicked: function(buttons) {
     if(buttons == 0)
     {
      // what to do here ?
     return true;
     }
     if(buttons == 1)
    {
     $scope.takeImage(Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
     return true;
     }}
     })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accomplished this by inserting `<input type="file" id="fileupload" style="display:none">` and in my controller I used

```
 if(buttons == 0)
   {
    // what to do here ?
    document.getElementById('fileupload').click()
         ...
    }
```

I hope this may help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cordova-plugin-file` plugin to handle file manager

> https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Install the plugin using

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`

then use the provided functions under `deviceready` event.

```
More info : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file
```

Comment: I am already using this plugin to upload image files or using `<input type="file">` problem is how to make a button in `$ionicActionSheet.show()`